# $0 in taxes if stock losses from previous year exceeds stock profits from this year?

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks, capital-gains-tax

Let's use this example for US taxes: let's say someone losses $50,000 in the stock market one year, then makes $50,000 the next year. Do they pay $0 in taxes for the latter year?

I see that you can deduct $3,000 per year from losses with a schedule D. But, I heard somewhere that you don't pay taxes on any stock profits until you break even on losses from previous years. Is this true?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Assuming that you had no gains in year ONE when you **realized** $50k in losses, you would deduct $3k on your taxes and have a carry forward loss  of $47k.

In year TWO you **realized** $50k in capital gains.  The $47k would be neutralized and you would pay taxes on $3k in year TWO.

Comment: But only if you do your paperwork correctly. One  can throw the advantage away by being stupid.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica That qualification applies to all tax calculations.

Comment: @Barmar - I've never heard of doing it wrong making it right ;->)

Comment: My real point is that it should go without saying.

Comment: Just in case a reader misses it, the very important keyword here is **realized**: just because your portfolio value goes down (or up) does *not* mean you deduct (or pay) taxes.  You have to actually sell your holdings in each year to *realize* the loss/gain.

Comment: Not applicable here but traders who apply for and are granted Trader Tax Status by the IRS use MTM accounting and can deduct the entire loss in the year it is realized