# Capital Gains taxes

Tags: capital-gains-tax, day-trading

I used to be an amateur options trader and lost several thousand dollars over the past 2 years.

I understand how the wash rule works but here is my question.
Let's say I lost 150,000 dollars over the past 2 years.

I know you can deduct 3000 a year for losses in the market. My question is this

If I gain 150,000 dollars this year as capital gains on short term trading, will I owe any taxes ?

Comment: You will not make hands over fist money. Everyone thinks they will. Nobody does. Delete that part and just ask your tax question.

Comment: Tax questions need a country tag.

Comment: Definitely an exact duplicate question. We just need to find the other one.

Comment: @JTP - Apologise to Monica♦ - This might be an existing [duplicate question](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/123869/0-in-taxes-if-stock-losses-from-previous-year-exceeds-stock-profits-from-this-y/123870#123870).

Comment: Ha. Yes, can't believe that was last April. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you deducted  $3k of your $150k loss in previous tax filings then you'll have less than $150k as a carryover deduction.  So if you make $150k this year, most of it will be offset by the carryover, just not whatever number of times you deducted $3k.